# Couldn't run the SQL Server 2019 installation file on Windows 11

Tags: sql-server, installation, sql-server-2019, windows-11, sql-server-2019-express

I am trying to install SQL Server 2019 for a non-production work on my personal laptop. I downloaded and tried running the SQL Server Express installer file but happened after the double click. I did the same Developer edition installer file as well. same result. I also tried running the files as administrator still same result. Laptop configuration is

```
Device Specifications:

Processor   Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-9750H CPU @ 2.60GHz   2.60 GHz
Installed RAM   16.0 GB (15.8 GB usable)
System type 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor
Pen and touch   No pen or touch input is available for this display
Hard disk : 512 GB (SSD Type)

Windows Specifications:
Edition Windows 11 Home Single Language
Version 21H2
Installed on    ‎21-‎09-‎2021
OS build    22000.675
Experience  Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.22000.675.0
```

[error_cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nkfeq.png)

Comment: Windows 11 Home supports SQL Server 2019 Express, Standard and Developer editions only. Did you get any kind of error message at all? Did you use "Run as Administrator" on the setup executables? Do you have anti-virus software "helping" by blocking the installation?

Comment: I have tried express and dev editions. I tried running the files from CMD which was run as administrator using 'start SQL2019-SSEI-Expr.exe'. got the error which I have added in the post as error_cmd link. I have uninstalled norton antivirus and tried these things but still no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the solution. issue was with latest windows update. Should manually turn on the .Net framework 3.5 in control panel > Programs > Turn windows features on or off. successfully installed after making the above change.